# 3 columns - center column fluid with an overflow element

Tags: html, css

I have a three column website. Outer columns are fixed, middle column is fluid.
I implemented this with

```
<div style="display:table">
    <div style="display:table-row">
        <div style="display:table-cell">
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-cell">
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-cell">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(see jsfiddle for complete code)

Now I have in the middle column an element that can become too wide.
I hide this with an

```
overflow:auto
```

so there will be scrollbars.

**EDIT:**
doesn't work sorry: http://jsfiddle.net/WtWCC/
does work:          http://jsfiddle.net/WtWCC/2/

Description for Chrome:
In the example provided click on the "+" till the scrollbar appears (the more you click the more clearly the problem) . The view with the scrollbar is what I like:  2 fixed columns visible, with the middle column maximized.

Now resize the browser. (or the jsfiddle pane)

The problem now is that the middle column becomes much bigger. An the right column get's hidden.

Anybody knows a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The described behaviour is in Chrome.
In IE and Firefox the Overflow:auto doesn't work at all.

Comment: The JS portion of the demo doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had problems with your JSFiddle, so sorry if this doesn't help you.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">
    Leftees
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Righties
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    Middies
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.left{
    float:left;
    background:red;
}
.middle{
    overflow:hidden;
    background:green;
}
.right{
    float:right;
    background:yellow;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WtWCC/1/%20%22jsfiddle)

Comment: Thx for your answer.  I know of this rather good css design.  The biggest problem I have with it, is that the order of the HTML isn't correct. As the HTML is rendered I can't (or not easily) change this (only with changing the dom through javascript).

Comment: @JDC That's an excellent point. This hack is definitely limited by having direct access to the HTML structure. Suppose you could instead switch what content is placed in what block in the view, but again you'd need direct access to it, and it's still more of a hack.

Comment: I voted this as answer as it is the only solution to do this. Although I knew this solution I think it still looks like a hack, and I only want to use it if nothing else works.  The rendering of what I initialliy did is in my humble opinion verry buggy in any browser.

Comment: @JDC I consider it a hack. It's nice that less these require hacks these days but they are still common. Be sure and come back to share if you find another solution.